# How to overlap searching result?

Tags: vimscript

Given that I have string `AABBAABBAA`. I cannot find two `AABBAA` with the `/` that vim provides. Is there any option to enable this behaviour or I need a script/plugin?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible if you unset flag `c` in setting [`'cpoptions'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#cpo) (alias `'cpo'`). Absence of that flag is [described thusly](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#cpo-c):

> When not present searching continues one character from the cursor position.  With 'c' "abababababab" only gets three matches when repeating "/abab", without 'c' there are five matches.

Now the simple pattern...

```
AABBAA
```

...will match both occurrences in the double quotes.

A more comprehensive illustration...

```
" Save current value
:let oldcpo=&cpo
" Unset 'c'
:set cpo-=c
" Search as needed
/AABBAA
n
...
" Restore previous value
:let &cpo=oldcpo
```

(This makes no assumptions about whether `c` is set to begin with, thus the save/restore of `oldcpo` as well as the unsetting of `c`.)

Comment: This solves my question, thank you! And I just find the neovim way to remove this option with `vim.opt.cpo:remove({'c'})`.